# Proving that togling the direction of a polytope triangle yields the empty set

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles, polygons, polytopes

A triangle in the plane can be defined as the intersection of three half planes, each defined by the line passing through one of the segments and a normal direction pointing towards the interior of the triangle.

One thing is, if you flip the direction of all 3 normal directions (i.e. you take the complement of the 3 half spaces) then the intersection of those half spaces is the empty set, no matter the triangle.

I am having a hard time proving that postulate.

Comment: You can affinely transform the triangle to this one: $$x\geq0,\;y\geq0,\;x+y\leq1$$ In other words, you can choose a skewed coordinate system such that your triangle is described by these inequalities. And it's obvious that the complementary system of inequalities has no solution: $$x\leq0,\;y\leq0,\;x+y\geq1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is a simple reason which I am going to express in a graphical way.

Have a look at the following figure:

[image]

The three extended sides (Red, Green, Blue) of the triangle define 7 regions, with a 3 digits binary code for each one.

Let us explain how the first (red) digit is defined.

The regions bearing a left digit number $\color{red}{1}$ are those situated on the same side of the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ line as the triangle, whereas it is a  $\color{red}{0}$ for the others.

The other digits (the Green and the Blue ones) are attributed with similar rules.

Now the final touch. You may have noticed that among the $2^3=8$ theoretically possible codes, one is absent : code $\color{red}{0}\color{green}{0}\color{blue}{0}$.

What is this missing region, otherwise said, what is the meaning of this void region ? Precisely what you are looking for, the fact that no point can be situated simultaneously at the exterior of red, green and blue lines with respect to the triangle...

Comment: @G Cab Hi ! How are you ? I have seen your attempt and I would have attempted the same kind of computation, when I thought to the "graphical proof" you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take any specific point from *within* that triangle and prove that it will be within neither of those halfspaces. Then observe that this behaviour does not change with the specific choice throughout its inner region.

--- rk

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question either. This answer is focusing on the inner region of the triangle. But the problem is not whether there are no points in the interior of the triangle. 

The postulate is that no point ANYWHERE is inside all 3 halfspaces at once. But there are infinitely many points that are inside 2 of them at any given time. This "prove that it will be within neither of those halfspaces" is only true for points inside the triangle, not the full plane.

Comment: My answer indeed only was about the region 111 (according to the other answer). In fact I assumed the other regions would be more obvious to you. But we might go on applying right the same idea. By symmetry you could restrict to investigate regions 011 and 001 additionally. Both of them bow to the exact same reasoning of mine. An according inner point would belong to 1 resp. 2 halfspaces, but being outside of the other(s). Then you might investigate the 3 lines themselves as well. Then you will be done finally.